# Arithmetic sequence with polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

I need assistance with the following question:

> Let $a,b,c$ be $3$ consecutive terms of an arithmetic progression. We know that one root of $ax^2+bx+c=0$  is $-5$ what is the second root?

I tried to write the terms like this: $a$, $a+d$, $a+2d$ and I plugged it to quadratic equation.

Comment: note that $a,a+d,a+2d$ are called the terms of arithmetic sequence

Comment: What did you get after putting $b=a+d$ and $c=a+2d$ into the quadratic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug $x=-5$ to find:
$$25a-5b+c=0$$
Since $a,b,c$ form arithmetic progression, then:
$$a+c=2b$$
From these two we can get:
$$c=15a$$
Now the second root is by the Vieta's formula:
$$-5x_2=\frac{c}{a} \Rightarrow x_2=-\frac15\cdot \frac{15a}{a}=-3.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Let $r$ be the second root then
$$\begin{cases}b/a=-(-5+r)\\ c/a=-5\cdot r\end{cases}$$
Now let $b=a+d$ and $c=a+2d$ and solve the linear system with respect to the unknowns $r$ and $d/a$. What is the value of $r$?